# Alternative mappings for different dialects

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem that some dialects don't support Xml.

Namely SQLite used for in-memory db unit tests. I have a solution, I can alter the mapping to use a custom type:

Mapping line from `ClassMap` suitable for SQL Server 2008:

```
Map(x => x.XmlField);
```

Mapping line from SQLite `ClassMap`:

```
Map(x => x.XmlField).CustomType<XmlUserType>();
```

How can I manage both and select based on dialect or database type?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution:

```
if (SomeStaticPropertyTellingItThisIsATest)
    Map(x => x.XmlField).CustomType<XmlUserType>();
else
    Map(x => x.XmlField);
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work for me and my SQLite tests, but still I wonder what is recommended path when you need to ship to say both SQL server and MySQL where xml is also not a valid column type.